# EF 6.x dbSet refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am using EF Code First approach for my model. I initialize my model with a SQLConnection like as below.

```
public myMODEL(DbConnection connection)
            : base(connection, false)
        {
        }
```

I have a repository where I initialize the connection to the database.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = serverName,
                InitialCatalog = databaseName,
                UserID = userId,
                Password = passWord,
                PersistSecurityInfo = true,
                MultipleActiveResultSets = true
            };

string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
SqlConnection _entConn = new SqlConnection(providerString);
```

and the model every time I make a call as following.

```
using (myMODEL _mymodel = new myMODEL(_entConn))        
{ 

}
```

I am using my repository as reference for a different project. After I initialize my repository in that project I store the same in application variable.

> To give simple idea of my structure
>
> An application variable =store> new object of repository [repository is
>   used as dll reference]
>
> Whenever I make call to the same repository's public method => internally I initialize a new object of connection and a 
>   new object of context

I am making queries as following

```
IQueryable<myset> mysetQuery = myMODEL.mysets.Where(m => ....);
var someList = mysetQuery.ToList();
```

Now though I am making changes in data in database, and am initializing connection and context everytime as I have said before, the EF query returns me previously stored values. I need the actual data from database. Anything I have missed.

Comment: are you referring the correct db on the conn ?

Comment: You say you initialize the repo every time but you also say "After I initialize my repository in that project I store the same in application variable." Do not cache/save your repo.Creating new DbContexts is very cheap

Comment: @Sampath yes I am Sampath.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I keep object of repo in application. but when I call my repo to get the values I initialize connection and context.

Comment: I see,by repo you probably mean some kind of Service.Then it doesn't make sense.If you create new Context you'll get the latest data.Check again your code,your problem is somewhere else.